# HTTP Status 404 on checkout on broadleafcommerce

Tags: mysql, spring, tomcat, broadleaf-commerce

I followed instructions on getting-started page.

Then configured the demo with mysql and tomcat as per instructions on
 
1) switch-to-mysql-tutorial page 
2) app-server-configuration for tomcat page.

initially the application was not able to reading proper values from context.xml it was complaining unknown database driver ${database.driver} I hardcoded the values and the problem solved.

now the demo runs fine but when i checkout it give 404 and url looks like

myip.domain:8082/mycompany/mycompany/checkout

same problem with login
domain:8082/mycompany/mycompany/login
and register
domain:8082/mycompany/mycompany/register

Is it normal for broadleaf to add app name twice in these actions, 
second where can i find mapping for these actions in the code.

**EDIT**
I followed instruction on http://www.broadleafcommerce.com/docs/core/current/getting-started

after setting up the projects i did right click on eclipse DemoSite>Run As>Maven install.
similarly for site>Run AS>Maven install.

then run tomcat-demo task from ant which looks like

```
<target name="tomcat-demo">
        <delete dir="war/WEB-INF/lib"/>
        <artifact:mvn mavenHome="${maven.home}" fork="true" jvmargs="-DbroadleafCoreDirectory=${broadleafCoreDirectory} -DbroadleafWorkspaceDirectory=${broadleafWorkspaceDirectory} -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -Xmx512M">
            <arg value="compile"/>
            <arg value="war:exploded"/>
            <arg value="tomcat7:run-war"/>
        </artifact:mvn>
    </target>
```

tomcat log

```
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_ORDER_ITEM_ADD_ATTR drop foreign key FKA466AB44B76B9466
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_ORDER_ITEM_ADD_ATTR' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_ORDER_ITEM_ADJUSTMENT drop foreign key FKA2658C82D5F3FAF4
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_ORDER_ITEM_ADJUSTMENT' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_ORDER_ITEM_ADJUSTMENT drop foreign key FKA2658C829AF166DF
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_ORDER_ITEM_ADJUSTMENT' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_ORDER_ITEM_ATTRIBUTE drop foreign key FK9F1ED0C79AF166DF
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_ORDER_ITEM_ATTRIBUTE' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_ORDER_ITEM_DTL_ADJ drop foreign key FK85F0248FD5F3FAF4
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_ORDER_ITEM_DTL_ADJ' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_ORDER_ITEM_DTL_ADJ drop foreign key FK85F0248FD4AEA2C0
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_ORDER_ITEM_DTL_ADJ' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_ORDER_ITEM_PRICE_DTL drop foreign key FK1FB64BF19AF166DF
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_ORDER_ITEM_PRICE_DTL' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_ORDER_MULTISHIP_OPTION drop foreign key FKB3D3F7D6C13085DD
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_ORDER_MULTISHIP_OPTION' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_ORDER_MULTISHIP_OPTION drop foreign key FKB3D3F7D681F34C7F
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_ORDER_MULTISHIP_OPTION' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_ORDER_MULTISHIP_OPTION drop foreign key FKB3D3F7D689FE8A02
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_ORDER_MULTISHIP_OPTION' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_ORDER_MULTISHIP_OPTION drop foreign key FKB3D3F7D69AF166DF
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_ORDER_MULTISHIP_OPTION' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_ORDER_OFFER_CODE_XREF drop foreign key FKFDF0E8533BB10F6D
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_ORDER_OFFER_CODE_XREF' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_ORDER_OFFER_CODE_XREF drop foreign key FKFDF0E85389FE8A02
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_ORDER_OFFER_CODE_XREF' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_ORDER_PAYMENT drop foreign key FK9517A14FC13085DD
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_ORDER_PAYMENT' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_ORDER_PAYMENT drop foreign key FK9517A14F89FE8A02
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_ORDER_PAYMENT' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_ORDER_PAYMENT_TRANSACTION drop foreign key FK86FDE7CE6A69DD9D
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_ORDER_PAYMENT_TRANSACTION' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_ORDER_PAYMENT_TRANSACTION drop foreign key FK86FDE7CEE1B66C71
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_ORDER_PAYMENT_TRANSACTION' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_PAGE drop foreign key FKF41BEDD5D49D3961
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_PAGE' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_PAGE_FLD_MAP drop foreign key FKE9EE09515AEDD08A
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_PAGE_FLD_MAP' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_PAGE_FLD_MAP drop foreign key FKE9EE0951883C2667
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_PAGE_FLD_MAP' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_PAGE_RULE_MAP drop foreign key FK1ABA0CA336D91846
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_PAGE_RULE_MAP' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_PAGE_RULE_MAP drop foreign key FK1ABA0CA3C38455DD
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_PAGE_RULE_MAP' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_PAGE_TMPLT drop foreign key FK325C9D5A1E1C128
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_PAGE_TMPLT' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_PAYMENT_LOG drop foreign key FKA43703453E2FC4F9
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_PAYMENT_LOG' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_PAYMENT_LOG drop foreign key FKA43703457470F437
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_PAYMENT_LOG' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_PGTMPLT_FLDGRP_XREF drop foreign key FK99D625F66A79BDB5
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_PGTMPLT_FLDGRP_XREF' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_PGTMPLT_FLDGRP_XREF drop foreign key FK99D625F6D49D3961
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_PGTMPLT_FLDGRP_XREF' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_PRODUCT drop foreign key FK5B95B7C9DF057C3F
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_PRODUCT' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_PRODUCT drop foreign key FK5B95B7C96D386535
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_PRODUCT' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTE drop foreign key FK56CE05865F11A0B7
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTE' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_PRODUCT_BUNDLE drop foreign key FK8CC5B85F11A0B7
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_PRODUCT_BUNDLE' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_PRODUCT_CROSS_SALE drop foreign key FK8324FB3C15D1A13D
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_PRODUCT_CROSS_SALE' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_PRODUCT_CROSS_SALE drop foreign key FK8324FB3C5F11A0B7
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_PRODUCT_CROSS_SALE' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_PRODUCT_CROSS_SALE drop foreign key FK8324FB3C62D84F9B
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_PRODUCT_CROSS_SALE' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_PRODUCT_FEATURED drop foreign key FK4C49FFE415D1A13D
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_PRODUCT_FEATURED' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_PRODUCT_FEATURED drop foreign key FK4C49FFE45F11A0B7
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_PRODUCT_FEATURED' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_PRODUCT_OPTION_VALUE drop foreign key FK6DEEEDBD92EA8136
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_PRODUCT_OPTION_VALUE' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_PRODUCT_OPTION_XREF drop foreign key FKDA42AB2F5F11A0B7
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_PRODUCT_OPTION_XREF' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_PRODUCT_OPTION_XREF drop foreign key FKDA42AB2F92EA8136
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_PRODUCT_OPTION_XREF' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_PRODUCT_SKU_XREF drop foreign key FKF2DBF6D35F11A0B7
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_PRODUCT_SKU_XREF' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_PRODUCT_SKU_XREF drop foreign key FKF2DBF6D3B78C9977
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_PRODUCT_SKU_XREF' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_PRODUCT_UP_SALE drop foreign key FKF69054F515D1A13D
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_PRODUCT_UP_SALE' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_PRODUCT_UP_SALE drop foreign key FKF69054F55F11A0B7
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_PRODUCT_UP_SALE' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_PRODUCT_UP_SALE drop foreign key FKF69054F562D84F9B
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_PRODUCT_UP_SALE' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_QUAL_CRIT_OFFER_XREF drop foreign key FKD592E919D5F3FAF4
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_QUAL_CRIT_OFFER_XREF' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_QUAL_CRIT_OFFER_XREF drop foreign key FKD592E9193615A91A
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_QUAL_CRIT_OFFER_XREF' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_QUAL_CRIT_PAGE_XREF drop foreign key FK874BE590883C2667
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_QUAL_CRIT_PAGE_XREF' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_QUAL_CRIT_PAGE_XREF drop foreign key FK874BE590378418CD
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_QUAL_CRIT_PAGE_XREF' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_QUAL_CRIT_SC_XREF drop foreign key FKC4A353AF13D95585
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_QUAL_CRIT_SC_XREF' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_QUAL_CRIT_SC_XREF drop foreign key FKC4A353AF85C77F2B
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_QUAL_CRIT_SC_XREF' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_RATING_DETAIL drop foreign key FKC9D04AD7470F437
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_RATING_DETAIL' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_RATING_DETAIL drop foreign key FKC9D04ADD4E76BF4
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_RATING_DETAIL' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_REVIEW_DETAIL drop foreign key FK9CD7E6927470F437
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_REVIEW_DETAIL' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_REVIEW_DETAIL drop foreign key FK9CD7E69245DC39E0
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_REVIEW_DETAIL' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_REVIEW_DETAIL drop foreign key FK9CD7E692D4E76BF4
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_REVIEW_DETAIL' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_REVIEW_FEEDBACK drop foreign key FK7CC929867470F437
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_REVIEW_FEEDBACK' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_REVIEW_FEEDBACK drop foreign key FK7CC92986AE4769D6
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_REVIEW_FEEDBACK' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_SANDBOX drop foreign key FKDD37A9A174160452
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_SANDBOX' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_SANDBOX_MGMT drop foreign key FK4845009F579FE59D
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_SANDBOX_MGMT' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_SC drop foreign key FK74EEB716A1E1C128
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_SC' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_SC drop foreign key FK74EEB71671EBFA46
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_SC' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_SC_FLDGRP_XREF drop foreign key FK71612AEA6A79BDB5
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_SC_FLDGRP_XREF' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_SC_FLDGRP_XREF drop foreign key FK71612AEAF6B0BA84
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_SC_FLDGRP_XREF' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_SC_FLD_MAP drop foreign key FKD9480192DD6FD28A
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_SC_FLD_MAP' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_SC_FLD_MAP drop foreign key FKD948019213D95585
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_SC_FLD_MAP' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_SC_RULE_MAP drop foreign key FK169F1C8256E51A06
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_SC_RULE_MAP' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_SC_RULE_MAP drop foreign key FK169F1C82156E72FC
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_SC_RULE_MAP' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_SC_TYPE drop foreign key FKE19886C3F6B0BA84
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_SC_TYPE' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_SEARCH_FACET drop foreign key FK4FFCC9863C3907C4
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:04 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_SEARCH_FACET' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:05 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_SEARCH_FACET_RANGE drop foreign key FK7EC3B124B96B1C93
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:05 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_SEARCH_FACET_RANGE' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:05 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_SEARCH_FACET_XREF drop foreign key FK35A63034DA7E1C7C
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:05 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_SEARCH_FACET_XREF' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:05 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_SEARCH_FACET_XREF drop foreign key FK35A63034B96B1C93
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:05 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_SEARCH_FACET_XREF' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:05 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_SITE_CATALOG drop foreign key FK5F3F2047843A8B63
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:05 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_SITE_CATALOG' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:05 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_SITE_CATALOG drop foreign key FK5F3F2047A350C7F1
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:05 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_SITE_CATALOG' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:05 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_SITE_MAP_CFG drop foreign key FK7012930FC50D449
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:05 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_SITE_MAP_CFG' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:05 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_SITE_MAP_GEN_CFG drop foreign key FK1D76000A340ED71
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:05 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_SITE_MAP_GEN_CFG' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:05 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_SITE_MAP_URL_ENTRY drop foreign key FKE2004FED36AFE1EE
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:05 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_SITE_MAP_URL_ENTRY' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:05 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_SKU drop foreign key FK28E82CF73E2FC4F9
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:05 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_SKU' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:05 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_SKU drop foreign key FK28E82CF77E555D75
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:05 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_SKU' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:05 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_SKU_ATTRIBUTE drop foreign key FK6C6A5934B78C9977
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:05 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_SKU_ATTRIBUTE' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:05 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_SKU_BUNDLE_ITEM drop foreign key FKD55968CCF29B96
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:05 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_SKU_BUNDLE_ITEM' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:05 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_SKU_BUNDLE_ITEM drop foreign key FKD55968B78C9977
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:05 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_SKU_BUNDLE_ITEM' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:05 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_SKU_FEE drop foreign key FKEEB7181E3E2FC4F9
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:05 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_SKU_FEE' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:05 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_SKU_FEE_XREF drop foreign key FKD88D409CB78C9977
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:05 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_SKU_FEE_XREF' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:05 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_SKU_FEE_XREF drop foreign key FKD88D409CCF4C9A82
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:05 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_SKU_FEE_XREF' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:05 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_SKU_FULFILLMENT_EXCLUDED drop foreign key FK84162D7381F34C7F
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:05 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_SKU_FULFILLMENT_EXCLUDED' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:05 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_SKU_FULFILLMENT_EXCLUDED drop foreign key FK84162D73B78C9977
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:05 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_SKU_FULFILLMENT_EXCLUDED' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:05 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_SKU_FULFILLMENT_FLAT_RATES drop foreign key FKC1988C9681F34C7F
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:05 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_SKU_FULFILLMENT_FLAT_RATES' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:05 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_SKU_FULFILLMENT_FLAT_RATES drop foreign key FKC1988C96B78C9977
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:05 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_SKU_FULFILLMENT_FLAT_RATES' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:05 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_SKU_MEDIA_MAP drop foreign key FKEB4AECF96E4720E0
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:05 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_SKU_MEDIA_MAP' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:05 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_SKU_MEDIA_MAP drop foreign key FKEB4AECF9D93D857F
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:05 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_SKU_MEDIA_MAP' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:05 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_SKU_OPTION_VALUE_XREF drop foreign key FK7B61DC0BB0C16A73
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:05 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_SKU_OPTION_VALUE_XREF' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:05 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_SKU_OPTION_VALUE_XREF drop foreign key FK7B61DC0BB78C9977
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:05 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_SKU_OPTION_VALUE_XREF' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:05 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_STATE drop foreign key FK8F94A1EBA46E16CF
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:05 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_STATE' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:05 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_TAR_CRIT_OFFER_XREF drop foreign key FK125F58033615A91A
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:05 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_TAR_CRIT_OFFER_XREF' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:05 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_TAR_CRIT_OFFER_XREF drop foreign key FK125F5803D5F3FAF4
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:05 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_TAR_CRIT_OFFER_XREF' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:05 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_TAX_DETAIL drop foreign key FKEABE4A4B3E2FC4F9
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:05 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_TAX_DETAIL' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:05 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_TAX_DETAIL drop foreign key FKEABE4A4BC50D449
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:05 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_TAX_DETAIL' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:05 SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table BLC_TRANS_ADDITNL_FIELDS drop foreign key FK376DDE4B9E955B1D
[artifact:mvn] [ERROR] 23:23:05 SchemaExport - Table 'broadleaf.BLC_TRANS_ADDITNL_FIELDS' doesn't exist
[artifact:mvn] [ WARN] 23:25:15 SolrResourceLoader - Can't find (or read) directory to add to classloader: lib (resolved as: /tmp/hamdan/solrhome/lib).
[artifact:mvn] [ WARN] 23:25:16 SolrCore - [reindex] Solr index directory '/tmp/hamdan/solrhome/core1dir/data/index' doesn't exist. Creating new index...
[artifact:mvn] [ WARN] 23:25:16 SolrCore - [primary] Solr index directory '/tmp/hamdan/solrhome/core0dir/data/index' doesn't exist. Creating new index...
[artifact:mvn] Oct 14, 2014 11:25:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
[artifact:mvn] INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'mycompany'
[artifact:mvn] [ WARN] 23:25:20 RuntimeEnvironmentPropertiesConfigurer - Unable to determine runtime environment, using default environment 'development'
[artifact:mvn] Oct 14, 2014 11:25:23 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
[artifact:mvn] INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8082"]
[artifact:mvn] [ WARN] 23:25:24 log - No trackers were found, not outputting Google Analytics script. Set the googleAnalytics.webPropertyId and/or the googleAnalytics.masterWebPropertyId system properties to output Google Analytics
[artifact:mvn] [ WARN] 23:25:32 PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/mycompany/mycompany/login] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mycompany'
[artifact:mvn] [ WARN] 23:25:34 log - No trackers were found, not outputting Google Analytics script. Set the googleAnalytics.webPropertyId and/or the googleAnalytics.masterWebPropertyId system properties to output Google Analytics
[artifact:mvn] [ WARN] 23:25:36 PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/mycompany/mycompany/register] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mycompany'
[artifact:mvn] [ WARN] 23:25:38 log - No trackers were found, not outputting Google Analytics script. Set the googleAnalytics.webPropertyId and/or the googleAnalytics.masterWebPropertyId system properties to output Google Analytics
[artifact:mvn] [ WARN] 23:25:40 log - No trackers were found, not outputting Google Analytics script. Set the googleAnalytics.webPropertyId and/or the googleAnalytics.masterWebPropertyId system properties to output Google Analytics
[artifact:mvn] [ WARN] 23:25:50 PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/mycompany/mycompany/checkout] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mycompany'
```

Comment: No that is not normal. How did you deploy the war file in your app server?

Comment: do you have some log files? It isn't normal to have the context duplicated, also from your comment it seems that you have changed default ports also.

Comment: Added logs, so is not allowed me to add more logs.

Comment: is your link http://domain:8082/mycompany/mycompany/login or https://domain:8082/mycompany/mycompany/login ?

Comment: both the links are same, what are you trying for ask?